# Why is the first method wrong and the second correct?

Tags: python, type-conversion

#FIRST METHOD(INCORRECT)

```
two_digit_number = input

number0 = two_digit_number[0]
number1 = two_digit_number[1]

int(number0)
int(number1)

result = number0 + number1
print(result)
```

#SECOND METHOD(CORRECT)

```
two_digit_number = input

number0 = two_digit_number[0]
number1 = two_digit_number[1]


result = int(number0) + int(number1)
print(result)
```

How does converting data types work?

Comment: `int(number0)` returns a converted value, and does not convert the variable in-place. So in the first example, you just ignore the result of conversion and proceed to add up the original values of `two_digit_number`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

In the first method, `number0` and `number1` were not transformed into int properly.

yes, you called `int()` function on them but the variables remained the same type.

I think you could have done it this way:

```
two_digit_number = input

number0 = two_digit_number[0]

number1 = two_digit_number[1]

number0 = int(number0)

number1 = int(number1)

result = number0 + number1
print(result)
```